# How to return multiple ID’s from a function

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I need to return ID’s of a table from a function based on input.

```sql
Create or replace function f(v_input nvarchar) 
Return v_table
Is 
  Select id bulk collect into v_table from table1 where user=v_input ;
  Return v_table
End;
```

And this function will be called in sql queries like

```
Select * from table2 where id in (f(abc));
```

This is the concept.

How can we do this programmatically in oracle? How to return multiple record id’s from a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

- a `BEGIN` keyword between `IS` and the start of the main block.
- a declaration for a variable to `BULK COLLECT INTO` between `IS` and `BEGIN`.
- the return type to be a type not the name of a variable.
- a semi-colon to terminate the reutrn statement.
- `NVARCHAR` should be `NVARCHAR2`.
- `USER` is a reserved word and you should not use this for a column name; if you do it must be as a quoted identifier.

Like this:

```sql
Create or replace function f(v_input nvarchar2) 
Return t_table
Is
  v_table t_table;
BEGIN
  Select id bulk collect into v_table from table1 where "USER"=v_input ;
  Return v_table;
End; 
/
```

Then, if you have created these:

```sql
CREATE TYPE t_table IS TABLE OF INTEGER;

CREATE TABLE table1 (id INTEGER, "USER" NVARCHAR2(20));

INSERT INTO table1 (id, "USER")
SELECT 1, N'user1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, N'user1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, N'user2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, N'user3' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (id) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Then:

```sql
Select * from table2 where id MEMBER OF f('user1');
```

or

```sql
Select * from table2 where id IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(f('user1')));
```

Outputs:

> | ID |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f03bd68a2e6a70aad0b9b0cfa8ba3e78)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Updated the function in the question . What is the efficient way to approach this? Cursor or table function or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Xyz Please do not fundamentally change the question as that invalidates existing answers. If you have a follow-up question then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 19c, version 19.7 and above you may use [SQL_MACRO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nfcon/details-sql-macros-282451004.html) concept for this purpose, which is a parameterized query.

As you may see, it is merged within the main query.

> ```
> create function f_get_ids(p_user in varchar2)
> return varchar2
> sql_macro(table)
> as
> begin
>   return q'[select id from table1 where user_name = p_user]';
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from table2
> where id in (select id from f_get_ids('User 1'))
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | DATA_
> -: | :----
>  1 | 001
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'TYPICAL')
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                             |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | SQL_ID  9ns9x68zjtvhy, child number 0                                         |
> | -------------------------------------                                         |
> | select * from table2 where id in (select id from f_get_ids('User 1'))         |
> |                                                                               |
> | Plan hash value: 2946371633                                                   |
> |                                                                               |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation          | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |        |       |       |     6 (100)|          | |
> | |*  1 |  HASH JOIN SEMI    |        |     1 |    17 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE2 |     4 |    28 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE1 |     1 |    10 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                               |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                           |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                           |
> |                                                                               |
> |    1 - access("ID"="ID")                                                      |
> |    3 - filter("USER_NAME"='User 1')                                           |
> |                                                                               |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a9032a1eb4be7d145a1ff59136889f7d)*

Comment: getting the error while compiling this in 19.0.0.0.0 version                                                 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     ; is default authid as cluster order using external    deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate    result_cache accessible rewrite 
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: @Xyz I'm sorry, table macro feature is available since version 19.7. Edited the answer.